# Evaluate Sum of Countifs with multiple OR Criteria within multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, evaluate

I have the following situation:

I need to count rows before applying a filter.
Let say I want for Column A certain exact values to filter (more than one) , an the same goes for column B and C.
I'm using Evaluate of Sum Countifs

```
x = Evaluate("Sum(COUNTIFS(A:A,{"Value 1","Value 2"},B:B,{"X","Y"},C:C,{"XXX","YYY"}))")
```

What I need is to count rows where Column A has "Value 1" **or** "Value 2", Column B "X" **or** "Y" **and** column C  "XXX" **or** "YYY"
But this approach doesn't seems to work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: double the `"` in the string.

Comment: Your double quotes inside your formula string are ending the string... You need double double quotes instead: `"Sum(COUNTIFS(A:A,{""Value 1"",""Value 2""},B:B,{""X"",""Y""},C:C,{""XXX"",""YYY""}))"` So that your literal double quote is escaped.

Comment: I use a more complicated formula, i've tried to simplify in the example. I use array of strings as input.                Evaluate("Sum(COUNTIFS(A:A," & Chr(34) & arZones(i) & Chr(34) & ",E:E,{""" & Join(arModels, """,""") & """},F:F,{""" & Join(arModSelect, """,""") & """},I:I," & Chr(34) & "=*-*" & Chr(34) & "))")

Comment: also realize that the way that this is written it is `(A=Value1 AND B=X AND C=XXX) OR (A=Value2 AND B=Y AND C=YYY)` not any combination.

Comment: As to your latest edit, you can't do three `OR` conditions.  The limit is two arrays, one horizontal the other vertical.  You will need to change to SUMPRODUCT formula which is a bit more complicated as you will want to limit the references to the data set and you will need to combinations of `+` and `*` of Boolean conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found my self the answer. The suggested comment made by Scott did the trick: using SUMPRODUCT instead of sum countifs

```
x = Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(" & rng1.Address & ",{""" & Join(arZonas, """,""") & """},0))*ISNUMBER(MATCH(" & rng3.Address & ",{""" & Join(arModSelect, """,""") & """},0))*--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*-*""," & rng4.Address & "))))")
```